# Uncaught ReferenceError; Not defined at VM340 Index.js;1

Tags: alert

I am taking a programming course on Udemy, one task was to create an Alert, 
This should have created a pop-up, nothing created.

**alert("My name is " + myName + ", welcome to my course " + yourName + "!");**

I tried to add spaces or reduce spaces, but I keep these errors. I can't find anything on online

I hope for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: provide code fragment

Comment: DevTools I entered: alert("My name is " + myName + ", welcome to my course " + yourName + "!"); should of created a pop-up, but error reads +Uncaught ReferenceError: myName is not Defined.